# How can I host ASP.NET WebAPI application on mac?

Tags: .net, macos, asp.net-web-api

I have application on ASP.NET WebApi technology. Write in VS for mac.

How can I host ASP.NET WebAPI application on mac? Which WebService I should use?

Thanks a lot)

Comment: In order to run on Mac, you need [ASP.NET _Core_ WebAPI](https://wannabeegeek.com/2016/08/06/running-your-first-asp-net-core-web-api-on-mac/).